# how to integrate unity in React native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, unity-game-engine, react-native

Is this possible to integrate / configure unity(game engine) with react native and develop the game based application? if yes, can you tell me  what is the procedure / architecture? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to integrate Unity with React Native if Unity already has their own cross platform solution?

Comment: App will have several feature, one of them is a game based on unity3d, rest of the app will be build on RN

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a WebGL component inside a RN app. And then load the game build from some server.

[react-unity-webgl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unity-webgl) can be helpful here.

Something on these lines

```
//constructor
this.unityContent = new UnityContent(
  "<YOUR_BUILD_FILE>",
  "<YOUR_UNITY_LOADER_FILE>"
);

//render
render() {
    return <Unity unityContent={this.unityContent} />;
}
```

[image]